# Most efficient/succinct way of combining queries with a filter?

Tags: mysql, sql

**Query #1:**

```
SELECT

destination_content.content,
destination_content.state

FROM destination_content
```

Gives me

```
State   Content
AZ      Lorem
AZ      Ipsum
AZ      Dolor
NC      Sit
NY      Blabla
```

**Query #2:**

```
SELECT

properties.state,
properties.name

FROM properties

WHERE properties.active = 1
```

Gives me

```
State   Content

AZ      Ritz Carlton
AZ      Hotel Malala
NY      Gilt NY
```

I want to combine query #1 to query #2 so that:

I get the results of query #1 but it's filtered so that the result for

```
NC   Sit
```

will not show up.

**End result should be:**

```
State   Content

AZ      Lorem
AZ      Ipsum
AZ      Dolor
NY      Blabla
```

Does not show up, because there is no active property in North Carolina. So I want to filter by active property states.

What's the most succinct way of combining these queries?

**EDIT:**
Maybe my brain isn't working ATM but I tried `INNER JOIN properties ON ( destination_content.state = properties.state )` but that gives me more rows results than I need. Originally I get back 230 because there are 230 content pieces, but it becomes around 1000 after that join. What did I forget?

Comment: Have you tried joining the two tables already? Or: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Yeah, I'm forgetting something, ugh.

Comment: You should be more careful when posting examples to SO. You select state name and in the result you suddently have state content, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should join the tables:

```
SELECT dc.content, dc.state
FROM destination_content dc
INNER JOIN properties p ON  ( dc.state = p.state AND dc.content = p.content )
WHERE p.active = 1
```

It should be much easier BTW to join tables if you'd have a primary key (ID) in each table.